# Multiple Optional Parameters JSDoc

Tags: google-closure-compiler, optional-parameters, jsdoc

I have a function in js with the following signature:

```
  function foo(name, opt_callback, opt_dataStr);
```

And I'm trying to annotate this using JSDoc for Closure compiler like so:

```
 /**
  * @param {string} name
  * @param {function(*)=} opt_callback
  * @param {string=} opt_dataStr
  */
```

But the compiler generates a dozen of type warnings every time opt_callback is not passed in and opt_dataStr is, complaining that I'm passing a string where I should have a function.
I'm sure there is a simple solution as to how annotate this correctly, but I've tried

```
 * @param {function(*)=|string=} opt_callback
```

and

```
 * @param {(function(*)|string)=} opt_callback
```

and so on, with no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last works, this compiles without warning:

```
/**
  * @param {string} name
  * @param {(function(*)|string)=} opt_callback
  * @param {string=} opt_dataStr
  */
function fn(name, opt_callback, opt_dataStr) {}

fn('a','b');
```

[Here is an example](http://closure-compiler-debugger.appspot.com/#input0%3D%252F**%250A%2520%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520name%250A%2520%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257B(function(*)%257Cstring)%253D%257D%2520opt_callback%250A%2520%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bstring%253D%257D%2520opt_dataStr%250A%2520%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520fn(name%252C%2520opt_callback%252C%2520opt_dataStr)%2520%257B%257D%250A%250Afn('a'%252C'b')%253B%250A%250A%26input1%26conformanceConfig%26externs%26refasterjs-template%26CHECK_SYMBOLS%3D1%26CHECK_TYPES%3D1%26MISSING_PROPERTIES%3D1)